# How to trim white spaces and wrong caracteres from an ip string?

Tags: ip, trim

In javascript i need to trim a given IPAddress to get only the string part of the ip

like if i have:

INPUT -> OUTPUT

"110.78.37.14" ➨ 110.78.37.14

110.78.37.14,  ➨ 110.78.37.14

110.78.37.14...➨ 110.78.37.14

i have got in my code something like this.

```
function validateIp(inputText) {

RegE = /^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}$/

    if(inputText.match(RegE)) {}    

    else{  

    alert('invalid ip plz enter an ip like 123.123.123.123');  

    refresh();

    }
}
```

But now i dont need this, i need that when it is an invalid ip automatly correct and put 123.123.123.123 by it self !
thanks in advance.

Comment: Ready captain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a javascript function like this:

```
function trimIp(ipString) {
 var regex = /(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}/g;
 var trimmed = ipString.match(regex);
    if (null == trimmed) {
        return "Not a valid IP number.";
    } else {
        return trimmed;
    }
}
```

Comment: i edited my original post, plz see it to see if toy can help me. Thanks!!